# Make a set of characters act as open/close syntax?

Tags: syntax-table, sexp

Is there a way to make a set of characters act syntactically as open/close brackets? For example, {a> as an opening bracket, and <a} as a closing bracket? I know how to do this with single characters, and am interested in whether doing it for a set is the right way to think about it.

I guess this is sort of like open and closing tags in html, but a little closer to s-exp syntax.